# Why these derivations use different ratios to calculate dm and can they be done using another ratio?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

My question is about the ways to derive these expressions. Why in the case of the thin circular plate dm = (M/A) * dA is used while in the thin rectangular plate dm = (M/V) * dV is used? Can they be derived using the other ratio instead of the one I already mentioned? For example, can you derive the expression for the thin circular plate from dm = (M/V) * dV and the expression for the thin rectangular plate from dm = (M/A) * dA?

Example (Thin Circular Plate Case) :

Ix = ∫(r^2)dm

dm = (M/A) * dA

A = πr^2

dA = 2πrdr

Ix = (M/A) ∫r^2 * 2πrdr

Ix = (2πM/πR^2) * (R^4/4) = (mR^2/2)

Can it be done using dm = (M/V) * dV ?

The same question is for the thin rectangular plate.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

starting with

$$\rho=\frac mV$$
where $~\rho~$ is the density .

if the density is constant then

$$dm=\rho\,dV=\frac mV\,dV$$

with $~V=L\,A~$

if L is constant then
$$dV=L\,dA$$
$$dm=\frac m{L\,A}\,L\,dA=\frac mA\,dA$$

thus if the density and the length of the body are constant,  you can use both equations for dm